# ASP.NET Core OAuth correlation cookie not found

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC application setup to use OAuth for authentication. As it is deployed as an Azure Web App, it has data protection services configured with keyvault and blob storage; however I'm still seeing correlation failures like below in our logs in production.

```
    Message: '.AspNetCore.Correlation.OAuth.VkmnPxJJLn91wYEb5HSO7A6zGjULwiVTKeEPHoO2GcA' cookie not found..
```

I do not see these errors locally or in our test environments, and we haven't experienced these errors when testing the website in production so don't know why we're seeing these in our logs. Any help identifying what could be causing these would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In this thread they suggest 3 things handle error when it occurs, connect azure nodes so the cookie is everywhere, set auth cookie timeout manually. https://community.auth0.com/t/asp-net-core-2-intermittent-correlation-failed-errors/11918/22

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've actually setup up the key ring via data protection services, and was redirecting correlation failures so it would bounce back to a page which required authorization but I'm still getting the errors. The only thing I haven't tried is setting the oauth cookie timeout.

Comment: I feel if you use docker it may help, may be you you creat a small test

Comment: Hey did you manage to find a solution for this?